# Speed with wind resistance

Tags: kinematics, vectors, relative-motion

This is probably a basic question, but it has been a while since I did anything like this.
If a boat is sailing forward at speed $x$ and the direction of the wind, with magnitude $y$, is either equal, opposite or perpendicular to the direction of the boat what would the new speed of the boat be? Something like $x-y$ or $x+y$?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for [Galilean formula for adding velocities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula)(since boats speeds are not relativistic ;) )

You always add the speeds but in vector form. This means that you will get a minus if they are opposed and a plus if they are in the same direction. But if they act on different lines, you need to find the third side of the triangle formed having the two velocities drawn with lengths proportional to their values, and forming an angle as the one formed by their respective directions.